# Save & Copy jmp_buf C++

Tags: c++, setjmp

Is it possible and valide to make a copy of jmp_buf and restore it later? something like

```
jmp_buf oldEnv = env;
int val = setjmp(env);
.......
env = oldEnv;
```

I have used memcopy() and sizeof(env), to copy jmp_buf data. This seems to work fine. is this just a coincidence?

Comment: `longjmp` isn't valid in C++ to begin with, you need to use exceptions for cross-function flow control, because C++ depends on proper stack unwinding.  `setjmp`/`longjmp` may be implemented with exceptions, but I  stack unwinding is not guaranteed.  What the Standard actually says: "A `setjmp`/`longjmp` call pair has undeﬁned behavior if replacing the `setjmp` and `longjmp` by `catch` and `throw` would invoke any non-trivial destructors for any automatic objects."

Answer (score 2):

You can do that only if you don't do anything with the `jmp_buf` in the interim.  Most notably, you can't call `setjmp` again, restore the old `jmp_buf` content, and use `longjmp` to get back to an earlier `setjmp` call.

The rule in the C Standard:

> The `longjmp` function restores the environment saved by **the most recent invocation of the `setjmp` macro** in the same invocation of the program with the corresponding `jmp_buf` argument.

Because `jmp_buf` is "an array type", the call to `longjmp` is actually passing a decayed pointer; it is the actual address of the `jmp_buf` that the above verbiage concerning "corresponding `jmp_buf` argument" references, and not merely its content.

I don't know how the Standard guarantees that you'll return to the context of the most recent `setbuf`, if you're been mucking with the contents of the `jmp_buf`, so I would treat any modification of the `jmp_buf` as making it completely unusable for `longjmp` purposes.

If you know something about the internal layout on your particular platform, and you're using `jmp_buf` to save processor context to go into a debug log, that sort of thing is fine.  But copies can't be used with `longjmp`.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/jmp_buf the type of jmp_buf is unspecified. So you don't know what you're going to get when you actually use a `jmp_buf` and sizeof might not be returning the actual size of the storage you're memory you'd want to copy. A memcpy and sizeof probably will work, but since you don't know for certain, you might wind up with all sorts of errors.

This also begs the question why you'd want to copy it? The contents of jmp_buf shouldn't be used at all by you. All that you're doing is providing the storage space for the OS to use when setjmp populates `env`. Like Ron Popeil said, "Set it and forget it."

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it safely is to implement your own [setjmp/longjmp](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/savestate.hpp) lookalike. Fortunately this is easy to do for most compiler/architecture pairs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of inaccurate information in the responses.

Ben is right in that `jmp_buf` cannot be reliably saved and restored, and cannot be reliably used with *automatic objects* with non-trivial destructors.  However, if the original question is actually how to save multiple non-local goto points, one solution is to just use a `jmp_buf` stack:

```cpp
jmp_buf env[2];
int env_index = 0;

// first/outer computation
if (setjmp(jmp_buf[env_index++], 0) == 0) {
   ...
   .. call second/inner computation here ..
   env_index--;
} else {
   ...
   env_index--;
}

// in second/inner computation
if (setjmp(jmp_buf[env_index++], 0) == 0) {
  .. do computation here ..
  env_index--;
} else {
  .. trap code here ..
  env_index--;
}
```

Regarding `setjmp`/`longjmp` vs. `try`/`catch` in C++: the only limitation on using `setjmp`/`longjmp` is when automatic objects with non-trivial destructors are created but not destroyed between `setjmp` and `longjmp` - that is, if I do something like `setjmp` followed by an auto-variable of `std::map<std::string, int> x;`, put a value or two into `x`, then `longjmp` - the destructor of `std::map` is not called to clean up the internal map allocation.  But if I have something like this:

```cpp
// some external library written purely in C
extern "C" do_some_floating_point_computation(params...);

void SIGFPE_handler(...) {
  ...
  .. do longjmp back to wrap_C_Computation_Library here ..
  .. after SIGFPE handling ..
}

SomeClass::wrap_C_Computation_Library(...) {
  .. set up SIGFPE handler ..
  .. setjmp ..
  do_some_floating_point_computation(params...);
  .. setjmp error handler
  .. clean up SIGFPE handler ..
}
```

there is nothing wrong with using `setjmp` in the class method and `longjmp` in the SIGFPE handler.  (Likewise, trapping some signal across C++ method invocations that don't rely on automatic objects with non-trivial destructors is also ok.)